# Simple NN with Lasagne and NoLearn

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, theano

I wanted to test nolearn and Lasagne with a simple neural network and train the XOR problem, but I run into odd problems.

The code below fails with the error `ValueError: Cannot have number of folds n_folds=5 greater than the number of samples: 4.`

```
import numpy as np

from lasagne.layers import DenseLayer
from lasagne.layers import InputLayer
from lasagne.nonlinearities import softmax, sigmoid
from nolearn.lasagne import TrainSplit

from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet

data_set = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
])

X = data_set[:, :2]
y = data_set[:, 2:]
X[0]
X = np.array(X).astype(np.float32)
y = np.array(y).ravel().astype(np.int32)

layers = [
    (InputLayer, {'shape': (None, X.shape[1],)}),
    (DenseLayer, {'num_units': 2}),
    (DenseLayer, {'num_units': 2, 'nonlinearity': softmax}),
]

net1 = NeuralNet(
    layers=layers,
    max_epochs=100,
    update_learning_rate=0.01,
    train_split=TrainSplit(eval_size=0),
    verbose=3,
)
net1.fit(X, y)
```

and if I double the training set (extending the `data_set` array by the same set), the network trains but doesn't converge. Why is that the case?

```
# Neural Network with 6 learnable parameters

## Layer information

  #  name      size
---  ------  ------
  0  input0       2
  1  dense1       2

  epoch    train loss    valid loss    train/val    valid acc  dur
-------  ------------  ------------  -----------  -----------  -----
      1           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.02s
      2           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.01s
      3           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
      4           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
      5           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
      6           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
      7           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
      8           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
      9           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
     10           nan           nan          nan      0.50000  0.00s
Out[217]:
NeuralNet(X_tensor_type=None,
     batch_iterator_test=<nolearn.lasagne.base.BatchIterator object at 0x1143ff190>,
     batch_iterator_train=<nolearn.lasagne.base.BatchIterator object at 0x1143ff050>,
     custom_scores=None,
     layers=[(<class 'lasagne.layers.input.InputLayer'>, {'shape': (None, 2)}), (<class 'lasagne.layers.dense.DenseLayer'>, {'num_units': 2, 'nonlinearity': <function linear at 0x114a60d70>})],
     loss=None, max_epochs=10, more_params={},
     objective=<function objective at 0x1143fdcf8>,
     objective_loss_function=<function categorical_crossentropy at 0x1142d5c80>,
     on_batch_finished=[],
     on_epoch_finished=[<nolearn.lasagne.handlers.PrintLog instance at 0x122e10fc8>],
     on_training_finished=[],
     on_training_started=[<nolearn.lasagne.handlers.PrintLayerInfo instance at 0x1213a2a28>],
     regression=False,
     train_split=<nolearn.lasagne.base.TrainSplit object at 0x1143ff210>,
     update=<function nesterov_momentum at 0x1142de5f0>,
     update_learning_rate=0.01, use_label_encoder=False, verbose=1,
     y_tensor_type=TensorType(int32, vector))
```

What am I misunderstanding about the simple lasagne setup?

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here or to http://stackoverflow.com/, since it looks more like a coding problem, although it is sort of in a gray area. Anyway, `nolearn.lasagne.NeuralNet` is performing cross-validation, actually calling `sklearn.cross_validation.KFold`. Your example is too simple, with only 4 samples at the input, it is trying to split them in train/test and it can't. Hope it helps anyway.